# How to this calculate summation formula more quickly

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Let
$$ S = \sum_{p=1}^{10^{11}} \sum_{q=1}^{10^{11}} (p-1)(q-1) 2^{\gcd(p,q)} $$
then how to calculate $ S \bmod 10^8 $ more quickly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In other words, start with $p=2,q=2$ to drop the zero terms, right?

Comment: @abiessu  YES  :D

Comment: With a base of $10^8$ it will be difficult to calculate this quickly; you have $10^{22}$ summation terms which no single computer could get through in less than $10^{10}$ seconds.  So you would need to precalculate some of the values and then chop the sum down that way.  More zero-term locations are everywhere that $10^8 | (p-1)(q-1)2^{gcd(p,q)}$, which is a very small subset of the total space.

Comment: One of the difficulties is deciding whether each square having values for $p,q (mod 10^8) \in [1, 10^8-1]$ is equivalent across this space.  The $2^{gcd(p,q)}$ term throws off a lot of otherwise-easy calculations.

Comment: There must be some way to structure it as a loop over the gcd.

Comment: Is this problem from programming contest?

Comment: Seems like multiplying out the product $(p-1)(q-1)$ so that you get $\sum \sum pq2^{(p,q)} - 2 \sum p \sum 2^{(p,q)} + \sum \sum 2^{(p,q)}$ reduces to 3 sums each with some nice structure.  That said, the problem seems to be posed suggestively, like theres a much cleaner solution in its current form.

Comment: @Norbert from programming problem but not contest